# Aircraft with load sensors in their undercarriage to calculate CG

Tags: avionics, weight-and-balance, sensors

In another question on SE aviation I read that certain aircraft have load sensors in their undercarriage to calculate CG. Which are these types?

> The technology to build load sensors into the undercarriage is
>   available and it appears that a few planes are equipped with it.

PS. I don't mean just the weight on wheels sensor which is more a switch than a measurement.

[Would an accurate weight of a loaded aircraft be helpful?](https://aviation.stackexchange.com/questions/33029/would-an-accurate-weight-of-a-loaded-aircraft-be-helpful)

Comment: What make you think a weight on wheel sensor device is just a switch?

Comment: @ManuH Oh, I'm sure I am wrong. But would love to be corrected. Thanks!